# How to add a drop down with values(pre defined) in flask app models?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to flask and I want to add drop down list to a form which has pre defined values(not taking from the DB). I created a model as follows.

```
class DeliveryDetails(Model):

    _tablename_ = 'deliverydetails'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    delivery_type = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
```

And view as follows.

```
class DeliveryDetailsView(ModelView, DeleteMixin):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(models.DeliveryDetails)
    list_columns = ['customer_name','delivery_type']
    search_columns = ['customer_name','delivery_type']
    edit_columns = ['customer_name','delivery_type']
    add_columns = edit_columns
    label_columns = {
        'customer_name': _("Customer Name"),
        'delivery_type': _("Delivery Type") }
```

I want to show `Air, Land,  Sea` as `Delivery Types` in a drop down list. please let me know is it possible to do as I mentioned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [WTF forms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField). In your WTF form use the following field:

```
dropdown_list = ['Air', 'Land', 'Sea'] # You can get this from your model
seqSimilarity = SelectField('Delivery Types', choices=dropdown_list, default=1)
```

**Alternatively**:

If you are using jinja template and want to do this without WTF form, then you can pass the `dropdown_list` as an argument in render_template(). Finally simply loop through the list and create the select in HTML.

In view file:

```
@app.route("/url_you_want")
def view_method():
    dropdown_list = ['Air', 'Land', 'Sea']
    return render_template('your_template.html', dropdown_list=dropdown_list)
```

Then in **your_template.html**

```
<select>
{% for each in dropdown_list %}
  <option value="{{each}}">{{each}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without wtf forms?

Comment: Are you using jinja template?

Comment: assume that the dropdown list values in a table, then how to do it?

Comment: In a table? Database table? html table?

Comment: data base table. lets say delivery types were stored in a table call delivery_types

Comment: I did as you explained in your answer. then how the drop down map with Delivery Types?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153764/discussion-between-manura-omal-and-nabin).